# Does Jesus Christ explicitly deny transmigration or explicitly state there's only one birth?

Tags: words-of-jesus, afterlife, hebrews, reincarnation

Mainstream Christianity does not subscribe to the belief of transmigration or rebirth as a real phenomenon.

And the popular reference to this is

> [Hebrews 9:27 English Standard Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%209%3A27&version=ESV)
> 27. And just as it is appointed
> for man to die once, and after that comes judgment

But this is attributed to at best Paul, but not Jesus.

> The text does not mention the name of its author, but was
> traditionally attributed to Paul the Apostle. Most of the Ancient
> Greek manuscripts, the Old Syriac Peshitto and some of the Old Latin
> manuscripts have the epistle to the Hebrews among Paul's letters. [5]
> However, doubt on Pauline authorship in the Roman Church is reported
> by Eusebius.[6] Modern biblical scholarship considers its authorship
> unknown,[7] written in deliberate imitation of the style of
> Paul,[8][9] with some contending that it was authored by Priscilla and
> Aquila.
>
> Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_the_Hebrews)

So, is there any source in Bible where Jesus Christ explicitly denies transmigration or explicitly state there's only one birth?

[Related article](https://www.ananda.org/free-inspiration/books/the-new-path/chapter-28/)

Comment: This question lacks research. Just searching under _transmigration_ brings up a [website which quotes hundreds of biblical texts against such an idea](https://www.openbible.info/topics/transmigration_of_the_soul) many of which words are recorded from the lips of Jesus.

Comment: The list of things that Jesus doesn't explicitly deny is very long.

Comment: It sounds like you are not so much wanting to ask a question as have a debate.

Comment: @DJClayworth nope, I started having a debate because instead of straight up answering my question, some people were like your question doesn't have research or were like we believe in other things which Jesus didn't say etc etc. So I had to defend myself showing I have done my fair share of research. My question is simple which verses attributed directly to Jesus explicitly denies transmigration? That's it, no debate needed.

Comment: Why would it matter if the only Scriptures denying transmigration were from epistles, not the words of Christ? “Every Scripture is God-breathed and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, and for instruction in righteousness, that each person who belongs to God may be complete, thoroughly equipped for every good work.” (2 Timothy 3:16-17, WEB)

Answer (score 3):

The words of Jesus on this subject are in the texts highlighted in bold. The others give other words, inspired by the Holy Spirit, to other believers.

Psalm 78:38-39

Ecclesiastes 9:3-6, 11 & 12:1-14

**Matthew chapter 23**

**Luke 13:1-5**

**John 5:28-29 & 9:1-5**

Romans 9:10-12

1 Corinthians 15:46-48

2 Corinthians 4:1-6 & 5:10

Hebrews 9:27-28

**Revelation 6:9-11**

The reason why the words in Revelation are attributed directly to the resurrected Jesus Christ, irrespective of who wrote the book of the Revelation, is that the one instructed to write, John, states at the outset that this was ***"A revelation of Jesus Christ, that God gave to him,*** to shew to his servants what must soon come to pass", and that ***it is "the testimony of Jesus Christ."*** Throughout the entire book, Jesus speaks and in chapter 6 it is Jesus who opens this 5th seal, whereafter the souls of martyrs under heaven's altar ask a question and are answered. The point is that they were martyred (died horribly), then their souls went to heaven, not into another living creature, and they are told to rest in heaven till the full number of martyrs has been reached. They are given white garments to wear, not a new body. New, resurrection bodies won't be given to clothe the souls of the departed dead till the Day of Resurrection and Judgment - still future - read ch. 21 vss. 4-15.

The words in Luke 13 are the direct words of Jesus, while on earth, and show that horrible deaths of people don't happen because they were more wicked than others, and so deserved such dreadful deaths; no, every person who does not repent before they die is heading for the adverse judgment of God. There won't be a second chance in some after-life. ***The reincarnation idea depends on the chance of an opportunity after death to improve ones-self and, if that happens, their next reincarnation will be better***, and so they can gradually work their way up some imagined "ladder" to higher levels.

Just read Jesus' warnings to religious zealots, who were meticulous in living admirably moral lives, as to them actually already earmarked for hell. That's in **Matthew chapter 13**. Nobody can read his denunciations of them, and their converts, in light of transmigration.

Finally, Jesus' direct words in **John** agree with the words of **Ecclesiastes 12:1-14** that when people die, their spirit returns to God, to await his judgment. Further, **Ecclesiastes 9:3-6** confirms all of that by saying that the dead know nothing, whereas the living know that they will die. This all adds up to repudiation of the transmigration idea, especially what Jesus said. So, **you can accept Hebrews 9:27 in that list, now knowing that it is in total harmony with all the other texts, and with what Jesus said, even if Jesus himself did not speak those words** in Hebrews 9:27.

Answer (score 0):

> transmigrate
> [ˌtranzmʌɪˈɡreɪt, ˌtrɑːnzmʌɪˈɡreɪt, ˌtransmʌɪˈɡreɪt, ˌtrɑːnsmʌɪˈɡreɪt]
>
> VERB
> (of the soul) pass into a different body after death.
> "his spirit would transmigrate into another being"
>
> RARE
> migrate.
> "they might transmigrate to those settlements"

Open Bible: One Birth (https://www.openbible.info/topics/one_birth)

Open Bible: Transmigration (https://www.openbible.info/topics/transmigration)

Open Bible: Reincarnation (https://www.openbible.info/topics/reincarnation)

Open Bible: Rebirth (https://www.openbible.info/topics/rebirth)

> **Hebrews 9:27** ESV
> And just as it is appointed for man to die once, and after that comes judgment,

> **Matthew 25:46** ESV
>
> And these will go away into eternal punishment, but the righteous into eternal life.”

You may want to read: https://www.compellingtruth.org/transmigration-of-souls.html.

> Reincarnation, karma, and transmigration of souls all leave out the existence of a Savior, forgiveness, and sometimes even a god.

Comment: The dialogue between God and the rich man in Luke 16 lends some insight as well.  +1